# "Python dictionary" functionality in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

In Python, one can define a dictionary like

```py
a = {
    'a': 'hhh',
    'b': 123,
    'jfa': {'j': 1.5, 'r': 'string'}
    }
```

In C++11, I see that you can

```cpp
std::map<std::string, int> a = {
  {"a", 1},
  {"hh", 4}
};
```

but really I'd like the values to differ in type (and particularly allow dictionaries as values). Is there an idiom or library that does allow for this? Is anything planned for the next standard?

Comment: Use `boost::any`, `boost::variant` or similar?

Comment: On the last part, GCC supports `std::experimental::any` from the Library Fundamentals TS. IIRC, `variant` is part of the LF2 TS, or maybe it's not even in there yet. There's been a lot of discussion on the design decisions of that in particular.

Comment: If your intended value types can be expressed as reasonable subclasses of some general (perhaps abstract) base class, then you can use smart pointers to instances. Otherwise you'd have to use some runtime type checking as with `boost::any` or `boost::variant` and that design smell is strong that it will probably kill you. Or seriously damage you. You Have Been Warned (TM).

Comment: I believe the point of boost::variant is that some operations can be compile time type-checked.  See [boost::apply_visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/apply_visitor.html).  I've never used it though.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Fully agreed. I saw many times, that almost every such situation can be resolved in better (in terms of performance) way. As for the question itself: C++ is strongly, statically typed language, while Python is dynamically typed (and in practice - *almost typeless*). I am somehow terrified, that more and more people think, that every language should have the same set of features. That's impossible. Questions like "This is my Ruby/Python code. How do I convert it to C/C++?" or "Is it possible to do X in C++ like I can do it in Java?" do not make any sense.

Comment: Perhaps look at JSON and YAML libraries, which have to offer similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is `boost::variant` (which allows a specific set of types to fit into an object) or `boost::any` which allows any type to be fit into the object. As far as I know both of them are being considered to be added to the standard library, but I'm more sure about `any`.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider Niels Lohmann’s excellent JSON for C++ library. Single header, permissive license, makes JSON a first class type.

Link here: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Example:

```
nlohmann::json myDict = {
  {"a", 1},
  {"hh", 4}
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea, even though it feels like a slight abuse of a JSON library.